# Javascript and Frame

Tags: javascript

The following code keeps showing a blank page.
I tried 2 different ways. 
It seems that either the function doesn't get called or that the frame doesn't get updated.
What is wrong?
Thx.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

var links = [];
links[0] = "http://www.cbs.com";
links[1] = "http://www.nbc.com";
links[2] = "http://www.cnn.com";
var x = 0;
var delay = 3000;
changeLink();

function changeLink()
{
document.getElementById("report").source = links[x];
// parent.report.location = links[x];
x = x + 1;
if( x > 2) { x = 0;}
setTimeout(function() { changeLink() }, delay);
}

</script>
<title>Report</title>
<body>
<frameset border="0" frameborder="0">
  <frame name="report" id="report" src="#" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
</frameset>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```

Comment: Open your JavaScript console. Look at the error messages you are likely to have.

Comment: It's 2016 Don't use framesets.

Comment: @torazaburo, Browser does not render `frameset` at all. What could be the reason ?

Comment: Most likely because there's nothing to render inside.

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
document.getElementById("report").source = links[x];
```

to

```
document.getElementById("report").src = links[x];
```

Also **Don't use frameset and frames**, use [iframe](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe) instead

```
<iframe name="report" id="report" src="#">
```

also add this `changeLink();` method call inside window load event

```
window.onload = function(){

changeLink();

};
```

Comment: `document.getElementById("report")` returns `null`

Comment: @RayonDabre I guess this is because report was not loaded into the dom yet, updated the post to address that

Comment: __NO__, _HTML <frameset> Tag Not Supported in HTML5_